# Url_Launcher to open any Maps Application on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter

I am using the url_launcher package in Flutter to open Google Maps or Apple Maps on Android and iOS. So far, it is working perfectly on Android devices; However, I am running into problems when trying to launch on iOS. If applicable, I would like to give the user the option to select (possibly from a bottom sheet?) which mapping application to use, but for right now I am just concerned with making it functional on iOS.

I have included necessary LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in my Info.plist file. I have researched the correct url schemes from both Google and Apple and I believe that they are right (pending reviewal of course). I have consulted other SO posts regarding this issue and have found no luck.

```
Future<bool> launchMap(String addressLine1) async {
    String urlGoogleMaps =
        "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$addressLine1";
    String urlAppleMaps = "https://maps.apple.com/?query=$addressLine1";
    if (await canLaunch(urlGoogleMaps)) {
      print('launching google url');
      await launch(urlGoogleMaps);
      return true;
    } else if (await canLaunch(urlAppleMaps)) {
      print('launching apple url');
      await launch(urlAppleMaps);
      return true;
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch maps';
    }
  }
```

and as stated previously - in my Info.plist:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>googlechromes</string>
        <string>comgooglemaps</string>
        <string>waze</string>
    </array>
```

and here is the onTap portion:

```
                        InkWell(
                          child: Text(
                            orderDetailModel.address().addressLine1,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: screenAwareSize(15, 30, context),
                            ),
                            maxLines: 1,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          ),
                          onTap: () => launchMap(orderDetailModel
                                  .address()
                                  .addressLine1 +
                              orderDetailModel.address().cityStatePostalCode()),
                        ),
```

I expect Google Maps url to open when the user clicks on the address1. If Google Maps is not available, then open Apple Maps. Currently I am receiving an "Unhandled Exception: Could Not Launch Maps."

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: Could not launch maps
#0      _OrderDetailsState.launchMap (package:etteo_mobile/widgets/order/order_detail.dart:359:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      _OrderDetailsState.topPart.<anonymous closure> (package:etteo_mobile/widgets/order/order_detail.dart:303:40)
#2      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:635:14)
#3      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:711:32)
#4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
#5      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:365:11)
#6      TapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:312:7)
#7      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27)
#8      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:222:20)
#9      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&<…>
```

**EDIT**
I have figured out how to open Maps based on Platform by using the import

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform;
```

and using the following code:

```
  launchMap(String addressLine1) async {
    // Android
    var url = 'geo:52.32,4.917';
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      // iOS
      url = 'http://maps.apple.com/?q=$addressLine1';
    }
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

However, now I believe the issue I am having is Parsing the address from the addressLine1 input and I am receiving the following message.

```
VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: Could not launch http://maps.apple.com/?q=123 Main StreetAlpharetta GA 30022
#0      _OrderDetailsState.launchMap (package:etteo_mobile/widgets/order/order_detail.dart:374:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      _OrderDetailsState.topPart.<anonymous closure> (package:etteo_mobile/widgets/order/order_detail.dart:304:40)
#2      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:635:14)
#3      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:711:32)
#4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
#5      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:365:11)
#6      TapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:312:7)
#7      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27)
#8      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestur<…>
```

Anyone else experience this before? Am I using the correct apple maps query parameter (q=)?

Thanks

**FIXED**

```
  launchMap(String addressLine1) async {
    // From a query
    final query = '$addressLine1';
    var addresses = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromQuery(query);
    Address first = addresses.first;
    //print("${first.featureName} : ${first.coordinates}");

    // Android
    var url = 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$addressLine1';
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      // iOS
      url =
          'http://maps.apple.com/?q=${first.coordinates.latitude},${first.coordinates.longitude}';
    }
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

Comment: The query parameter ("q") is correct. Are you passing url encoded parameter ? e.g. no spaces in the query

Comment: @sukhi I ended up Geocoding the address and passing in lat, long that way. Apple url apparently liked that format better.

Answer (score 3):

You need to follow Apple Maps URL Scheme from this [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html). To perform a search, `q` parameter should be used.

`'http://maps.apple.com/?q=Place+Name'`

To use latitude and longitude, either `ll` or `sll` parameters can be used. Note that using `sll` will search for locations with the specified coordinates.

`'http://maps.apple.com/?ll=$lat,$long'`

Another option that you can explore is by using [maps_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/maps_launcher) plugin. This plugin automatically handles the map query depending on the platform that you're using.